# How to setup partitions on my boot disk with cloud-config?

Tags: partitioning, mount, cloud-init

I try to initialize an ubuntu 16.04 server via cloud-init. While booting the server the first time I wanna create the following partitions:

- root-fs (ext4 filesystem ubuntu)
- data-disk (xfs formatted partition)
- swap disk (4gb)

when I boot the machine regularly (without any cloud-init) I have a sda and sda1 (I think sda1 is the swap).

- Can someone help me out with a "valid" or "working" example or help me correct my approach?
- Or is this impossible to make partitions on the disk where I am sitting on?

*btw. my host is Hetzner*

This is my current approach:

```
#cloud-config
device_aliases: {'root-disk': '/dev/sda'}
resize_rootfs: true

disk_setup:
  root-disk:
    table_type: 'gpt'
    layout:
      - 75
      - [25, 82]
    overwrite: true

fs_setup:
  - label: root-fs
    device: 'root-disk'
    filesystem: 'ext4'
  - label: data-disk
    device: root-disk
    filesystem: 'xfs'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To close that task I post here my answer:
Important to know is, that `resize_rootfs` has to be `false`
I also ended up using `mbr` instead of `gpt` only because I couldn't figure out how to evolve with gpt. Maybe someone could post that example too.

```
#cloud-config
resize_rootfs: false

disk_setup:
  /dev/sda:
    table_type: 'mbr'
    layout:
      - 25
      - 75
    overwrite: true

fs_setup:
  - label: root_fs
    filesystem: 'ext4'
    device: /dev/sda
    partition: sda1
    overwrite: true
  - label: data_disk
    filesystem: 'xfs'
    device: /dev/sda
    partition: sda2
    overwrite: true

# now we attach the settings
runcmd:
  - [ partx, --update, /dev/sda ]
  - [ mkfs.xfs, /dev/sda2 ]
  - [ partprobe ]
  - parted /dev/sda set 1 boot on p

mounts:
  - ["/dev/sda1", "/"]
  - ["/dev/sda2", "/data-disk"]
```

Comment: Here is my "official" gist. Improvements ending up there: https://gist.github.com/exocode/a7e12b063f23a1ef899b23bcbfc7d123

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. That's exactly what i was trying to do as well.